# Close Menu Nav On Click JS

Tags: javascript, menu, nav

I'm working on a menu nav with JS and I would like to make it close after click. This is the JS code that I'm working with… Thanks in advance! :-)

```
'use strict';

(function() {
  var body = document.body;
  var burgerMenu = document.getElementsByClassName('b-menu')[0];
  var burgerContain = document.getElementsByClassName('b-container')[0];
  var burgerNav = document.getElementsByClassName('b-nav')[0];

  burgerMenu.addEventListener('click', function toggleClasses() {
    [body, burgerContain, burgerNav].forEach(function (el) {
      el.classList.toggle('open');
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

I tried many things but nothing worked well…

Comment: Please consider investigating and leaving the details of what you have tried so far and whats exactly not working , rather than just sharing the code, It would really add value to whoever has similer issues

Comment: I'm using this burger from codepen: https://codepen.io/mblode/pen/qEGWwB. If you use it with links in the same page doesn't close the menu. Hope it helps to understand and thanks a lot for your help!